# Write to an output matrix in C++. Errors with constructor

Tags: c++, matrix, matrix-multiplication

The primary objective is to write four methods that will write in to my text-c file. I can't use data[i] or data[j] because the array is variable sized.Since we want the element at row i and column j, I will use instead use data[i*m+j].

For the first method;
I will read one number as a double from the file into the variable value.Which will then read in the data from filename into the data array and then use fopen to open the file and fsscanf to read the data. I called two nested loops that iterated over my matrix array going through the rows in the outer loop and columns in the inner loop. This seems fine so far.

The second method; Copy constructor.
I simply iterated over the original data and copied the values into the new object data or B.

For the third method; Overload operator;
Multiplied the current matrix and the b matrix with a series of nested loops. The first two I wanted to iterate over the i and j rows and columns of the ouput matrix out. The third and innermost loop will iterate over the i-th row of the current data and the j-th column of b data to do the dot product. This innermost loop will do an accumulation of the
multiplications to calculate the dot product and the accumulated sum will go into the
out.data element at row i and column j.

The fourth method; write
This method should write to the output file in the same format as the input matrix files.
I'm using the fprintf function to print the data to the file
fprintf(file, "%f ", value);
I iterated over the rows and columns of data to print each element of
the matrix to the file. I also attempted to put a newline at the end of each.

Yet'ive gotten these errors
[Debugging errors][2]

Here's my code.

```
#include "Matrix.h"
#include <stdio.h>

Matrix::Matrix(int m, char *filename): size(m)
{
    double value;
    data = new double[size *size];
    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r");
    //This will read one number as a double from the file into the variable value.
    // TODO read in the data from filename into the data array
    // use fopen to open te file and fsscanf to read te data
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)  // for our rows.
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++);
        {
            fscanf(file, "%lf", &value);
        }
 }
{
    //Create two nested loops that iterate over matrix array going through our rows in the outer loop and the columns in the inner loop to read the data from the file into the data array of data[i*m+j];
    Matrix::Matrix(int m)
    : size(m)
    {
        data = new double[size *size];
    }

    Matrix(const Matrix &original)  
        : size(original.size)
        {
            data = new double[size *size];
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                data[i *m + j] = original.data[i *m + j];
            }
        }

    // TODO copy te data from the original matrix into this object's matrix
}

Matrix::~Matrix()
{
    delete[] data;
}

 Matrix Matrix::operator * (Matrix &b) const    
 {
    Matrix out(size);
    int sum = 0;
    int i = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            //Do the multiplication
            double sum = 0.0;
            for (int k = 0; k < size; k++)
            {
                sum += original.data*[i*size + j]*b.data*[k*m + j]
            }
        }

        out.data[i*size + j] = sum; // 
    }

    // TODO do the multiply and put the result into the out matrix
    return out;
}

void Matrix::write(char *filename)
{   
    int size = 0;
    double value;
    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "w");
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            fprintf(file, "%.2f", value);
        }

        fprintf(file, "\n");    // print a new line
    }

    // TODO write the matrix out to the file with each row on one line with
    // the data separated by spaces.

    fclose(file);
}
```

*So with this it mentions that there needs to be a primary expression before 'int'. Wouldn't this not be changed from it's original matrix-cpp file?
cannot call constructor ‘Matrix::Matrix’ directly [-fpermissive]
*Stumped on this as I assumed the constructor could be called directly.
Main file

```
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include "Matrix.h"
    int main(int argc, char **argv)
    {
     int m = atoi(argv[1]);
     Matrix A(m, argv[2]);
     Matrix B(m, argv[3]);
     Matrix C = A * B;
    
     C.write(argv[4])

;
}
```

my class or header file

```
class Matrix {
public:
    Matrix(int);
    Matrix(int, char *);
    Matrix(const Matrix &);
    ~Matrix();
    Matrix operator*(Matrix&) const;
    void write(char *);
private:
    int size; // data array
    double *data; //data variable
};
```

2.3 1.9 0.5
1.5 1.3 3.1
3.3 1.2 2.5
A-matrix.txt file

1.2 2.3 3.2
2.6 0.3 2.1
3.1 1.1 2.7
b-matrix.txt file.

The dot product of these files will be read and written to another text file to produce a 3x3 matrix, yet I've had difficulty due to errors above.

Comment: [Rubber ducky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) wants to know where `j` came from in `data[i *m + j] = original.data[i *m + j];` Discuss with the duck for a while and it'll probably talk you out of `j` entirely.

Comment: Side note: [The Rule of Three](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) suggests that if you need a copy constructor, you probably need an assignment operator and a destructor to go with it.

Comment: I used J, to represent the column.

Comment: What is the code starting with `{    //Create`  then you have class members implemented in a block.

Comment: Filling in for the duck, Do you need columns with a single loop performing a copy of a 1 dimensional array?

Comment: There's no code there along that line with the comment but under the comment, that's where that part of the code begins at  Matrix::Matrix(int m)
    : size(m)
    {
        data = new double[size *size];
    }

Comment: Unrelated: In `fscanf(file, "%lf", &value);`, check the return code from `fscanf` The file may end early or contain something that isn't a floating point number. `fscanf` will will you that there was an error and save you a ton of debugging.

Comment: I want to map the 2D matrix into a 1D array row by row. The output should have three rows and three columns.

Comment: Looks like `sum += original.data*[i*size + j]*b.data*[k*m + j]` has a couple extra `*` getting in the way. For example, `original.data*[i*size + j]` should be `original.data[i*size + j]`

Comment: `fprintf(file, "%.2f", value);`. Why value? Shouldn't you be printing one of the array elements in `data`? Specifically, `data[i*size + j]`? It also occurs to me that you'll need something to tell one number from another. `fprintf(file, "%.2f<add an extra space here>", data[i*size + j]);` should make it easier to read the numbers back out of the file.

Comment: You really shouldn't need to write several long paragraphs describing your entire program's behavior if your question is actually about compiler errors.  Simply show the errors and the code.  Please don't try to paraphrase the compiler errors.  Paste them in verbatim.  It does not matter whether you understand it or not.  Obviously you're here because you don't understand it, which is all the more reason _not_ to interpret the error and hide its original message.

Comment: Suggestion: write less code at a time. Write just barely enough code to have one easily-testable task. Then compile it, fix all warnings and errors (do NOT ignore the warnings as they are the compiler telling you that the program compiles but probably doesn't work as expected) and test that you receive exactly the behaviour you want (That means you get the right answer for good inputs and bad input s are correctly handled. Don't stop with getting the right answer for good data; it's the bad data that'll get you). Once everything works exactly as desired, write another small piece of code.

Comment: Don't let errors build up or you'll spend far, far more time untangling them than you would have if you dealt with them one by one.

Comment: Example: With a tiny example like this: https://godbolt.org/z/rjjKr6zYd it is easy to see that there is a brace in the wrong direction that leads to a massive and intimidating storm of compiler errors.